# List all Public IP Addresses used in all projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Cloud Platform.

I know that we can list the Public IP Addresses used by **instances** using the gcloud command like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/27994033.

I also have found out how to get the Public IP Addresses used by **load balancers** with the help of [this blog post](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/google-cloud-platform-http-load-balancers-explaine).

However, I am nearly certain that those two lists do not represent the complete Public IP addresses I'm using.

What other the services that can hold Public IP addresses? And what command I can use to retrieve those lists?

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have any specific command the list all the IP addresses associated with a project. You can open a feature request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) about this feature.

You can list all the Static IP addresses used in your project, using this command [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list). There is also a [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/) that provides IP address associated with the forwarding rules used in LoadBalancer. According to the Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950953/10415226), below is a command that provides the external IPs for all the instances.

```
gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list
```

Comment: So, does it mean we couldn't list any dynamic allocated public IP through the following command?
"gcloud compute addresses list"
Only the following command could show dynamic public IP?
"gcloud compute instances list"
Because I used the "addresses list" which shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The following command seems to also include load-balancer and NAT gateways:

```
gcloud compute addresses list --filter=addressType:EXTERNAL
```

Command docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the `Asset inventory` in `IAM and admin`.

You can use Big Query SQL syntax to grep through all the metadata information in your Google Cloud organisation.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT
  resource.data.name,
  resource.data.address,
  resource.data.status,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(resource.data.region, r'.*/projects/(.*)/regions/.*', '\\1') AS projectId,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(resource.data.region, r'.*/regions/(.*)', '\\1') AS region
FROM
  compute_googleapis_com_Address
```